# Get information from a listItem onClick with _id

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sqlite

I have a listview populated by a database. The listview displays some columns of the database. I want to be able to click the listItem and display a new activity that shows that whole record. I am trying to do this by passing the id between through an intent but it is not working. The activity is starting but the textViews aren't being populated. I have included the relevent code snippets here. Would really appreciate some help

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    ....
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...
        ...  
    }

    private void fillList() {
        ListView lv = getListView();

        Cursor c = db.getData();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        CustomCursorAdapter adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), c);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProductDetails.class);
                k.putExtra("item_id", id);
                startActivity(k);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**ProdDetails**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        db = new ProdDB(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.product_details);
        db.open();

        long id = getIntent().getLongExtra("item_id", 0);

        Cursor cursor = db.getDetails(id);
        while(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            tv1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProdDB.KEY_PRODCODE)));
            tv2.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProdDB.KEY_PRODNAME)));
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**DB.getDetails() - from ProdDB**

```
String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, 
        KEY_PRODCODE,
        KEY_PRODNAME,
        KEY_PRODTYPE,
        KEY_PRODCAT,
        KEY_PRODPRICE,
        KEY_PRODRRP,
        KEY_PRODSUPPLIER,
        KEY_NOTES};
return db.query(DB_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: 1. Do you have the same `id` in both activity? 
2. If you do, check function get data. Try to log cursor value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're having issue cause you're using `while(cursor.moveToFirst()){`. if you must use the `while` loop then you should use the `.moveToNext()` instead. Otherwise, you can just take out the `while` loop for moveToFirst since i'm assuming you only need the one row. as for why, don't ask me, i couldn't tell you.